# In c++, how does the language handle type promotion of char to integers in an iteration?

Tags: c++, for-loop, type-conversion, integer, type-promotion

The idea of this project was to create an array of characters with numbers like this.

```
char some_numbers[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};
```

I made an integer of the size of that array right below that with.

```
int array_size = sizeof(some_numbers) / sizeof(*some_numbers);
```

What I wanted to try out was a simple iteration where instead of going through each iteration to show characters, I simply wanted to just type promote within the for loop to show a true integer. For example, I know that if you changed some_numbers[0] to an integer, you will get a value of 48. I used just this very idea of type promotion inside the for loop parameters that I created like this.

```
for (int i = int(some_numbers[0]); i <= int(some_numbers[array_size]); ++i)
```

What I did next was simply just have the body of this for loop execute a simple arithmetic expression to show a real integer value. This is the whole thing I typed out.

```
for (int i = int(some_numbers[0]); i <= int(some_numbers[array_size]); ++i)
{
   std::cout << int(some_numbers[i]) - int(some_numbers[0]) << std::endl;
}
```

The whole thing that I wanted as an output was 0 1 2 3 4 5 but I'm just not getting anything. Where and what went wrong? How exactly should I shift my approach in the first place to get the output in the correct way for the correct data type I want?

Comment: `some_numbers[array_size]` will be out of bounds. The last element would be `array_size - 1`.

Comment: `some_numbers[i]` is also not likely to be part of the array. `'0'`, the first value `i` takes, is usually 48 so your first iteration would access `some_number[48]`. You probably meant `i - some_numbers[0]`.

Comment: What you're doing with that loop can be done like `for (char i = '0'; i <= '5'; ++i) { std::cout << "5 - " << i << " = " << '5' - i << '\n'; }`